# anonymous number appended to the original selected value from HtmlHelper DropDownListFor MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have an MVC razor view that captures the credit card information of the user. The month property of CC expiration date is bounded to a selectlist of type byte array.

```
private static readonly byte[] Months = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
public static SelectList GetMonthsSelectListthis HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return new SelectList(Months);
    }
```

The months model property is rendered using custom HtmlHelper DropdownlistFor extension -

```
@Html.DropDownListForWithDisplayNameAsOptionLabel(x => x.CardExpirationMonth, Html.GetMonthsSelectList(), new { @required = "required" })
```

This eventually calls in standard MVC html.DropDownListFor-

```
public static IHtmlString DropDownListForWithDisplayNameAsOptionLabel<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var modelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
        return helper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectListItems, modelMetadata.GetDisplayName(), htmlAttributes);
    }
```

Upon postback, the model binder normally picks up the value selected between 1-12.

However, sporadically we found that the card month which gets sent to the payment gateway is not between 1-12. Rather there is an extra digit that gets appended to the actual selected value causing transactions to fail.

Ex.

1. when 11 is selected 11**7** gets passed
2. when 5  is selected 5**3** gets passed
3. when 9 is selected 9**9** gets passed

The issue is happening in the production and affecting a small set of credit card transactions.

Upon debugging upon postback, I always find the correct value from the model binder. Do not really understand how the anonymous digit gets appended to the original selected value.

Appreciate any pointers to debug the issue further.

Comment: Check the view source of the SELECT. Is it rendering the correct option values ?

Comment: Yep, it does have all the option values. As I mentioned previously this is a sporadic behavior I am trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: Have you tried ModelState.Clear(); after transaction success..it might append the old values to the current values..

Comment: @Ganesh, so if I am understanding correctly you mean that model binder may append old values to new values? And ModelState.Clear() is just a way to confirm that does not happen.

Comment: Yeah @abhi .. can you cross check in console watch??

Comment: Tried it Ganesh. The issue is I am unable to replicate the behavior. Its sporadic with no definitive pattern observed.